# Getting closest input value from clicked element with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following markup:

```
<div class="options">
  <div class="quantity">
     <label>Qty:</label>
     <input type="text" name="quantity" value="1"/>
  </div>
  <div class="buttons">
    <a href="#" class="add">Add Item</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

I have a click event binded to the 'add' class using jQuery.  When I click that, I'd like to get the value of name="quantity", but there are several places that 'add' is clicked and several quantity fields.

I'm trying to get the 'closest' input value.  I've tried using 'closest' and 'findall' , but no luck.

Any idea how I can get this using jQuery? Thank you!

Comment: I've never heard about a jQuery method `findall`. I suggest you go through the [traversal methods](http://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/) and have a look at them. `closest` is already a good start. Please post the code you have so far.

Answer (score 55):

```
$(".add").on("click", function () {
    var val = $(this).closest("div.options").find("input[name='quantity']").val();
});
```

The strategy here is:

- Use [`closest`](http://api.jquery.com/closest) to find the closest ancestor matching the given selector (in this case a `div` with class `option`)
- Then use [`find`](http://api.jquery.com/find) to find the `input` with the given `name` using the [attribute equals selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/).
- Finally, use [`val`](http://api.jquery.com/val) to retrieve the value of the `input`.

Answer (score 9):

You need to use `closest` to find the proper enclosing element and then work from there.

```
$(link).closest(".options").find("input[name=quantity]")
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$(this).parent().parent().find("input[name=quantity]").val()
```

This should do the trick

Comment: Good spot my bad I would still suggest using closest however edited my answer any way for correctness

Answer (score 0):

I guess closest works only with same level elements. so..

Why not to put id to the input field and select by `$('#input-id')`?

Or traverse up to class options and find input in there: `$(this).parents('.options:first').find('input');`

Comment: `closest` finds the closest ancestor in the DOM matching the selector. `parents` finds all ancestor matching the selector.

Comment: Just repaired that, addad :first. So closest works searches dom upwards? Smarter again.. :)